# What is the fastest way to solve this system by hand?

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

$$x^2 - 3y^2 = 1$$
$$5y = 3x - 1$$

I've already tried substitution from the second equation to the first, but that ended up too complicated for me to do by hand. Any method other than the use of a calculator of any kind is allowed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to avoid fractions, multiply the first equation by $9$ and write it as $(3x)^2-27y^2=9$ then substitute $3x=5y+1$ which gives a straightforward quadratic in $y$..

Comment: Remember you can clear fractions by multiplying both sides by the LCD. Just get practice powering through substitutions like this.

Comment: @dxiv +1 because I think your method is a bit faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x^2 - 3 \left( \frac{3x-1}{5}\right)^2 = 1$$

$$25x^2-3(3x-1)^2 = 25$$

$$25x^2-3(9x^2-6x+1)=25$$

$$-2x^2+18x-28=0$$

$$-x^2+9x-14=0$$

$$x^2-9x+14=0$$

$$(x-2)(x-7)=0$$

I believe the rest should be manageable.

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought this problem was a lot harder to solve before you showed me this.